# How to tar folder on windows server 2019

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jenkins-pipeline, tar, windows-server-2019

I have the below path in my `jenkins` worksapce:

```
Report Services\bin\Release\
```

How can I `tar` this folder from `Jenkinsfile` (the command runs against `windows server 2019` server)?
Per my understating, `tar.exe` and `curl.exe` were first included with Windows Server 2019.

I tried the below in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
bat "tar -cvzf output.tar.gz Report Services\\bin\\Release"
```

but I keep getting error of:

```
tar: Report: Couldn't find file: No such file or directory
tar: Services/bin/Release: Couldn't find file: No such file or directory
```

In addition, to improve it, how can I tar only the `*.rdl` files from this directory?

Comment: Have you tried quoting your path containing spaces? Perhaps double-quotes will do that, but you'd need to escape those as you did your backward slashes, e.g. `bat "tar -cvzf output.tar.gz \"Report Services\\bin\\Release\""`

Comment: @Compo you are right, you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: also, how do I modify it to tar only specific extension in the path?

Comment: Have you tire using the wildcard/glob, `*.rdl`? You may find that changineg the current working directory to `".\Report Services\bin\Release"` first is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `"` and `\` replaced with `\\` :
Please see below example:

```
bat "tar -cvzf output.tar.gz \"Report Services\\bin\\Release\""
```

If you want to tar certain files :

```
bat "tar -cvzf output.tar.gz \"Report Services\\bin\\Release\\*.rdl\""
```

Comment: Tnx, I accepted it, but note that the second command is not working: `WorkflowScript: 18: unexpected char: '\' @ line 18, column 69.
   "Report Services\\bin\\Release\*.rdl""`

Comment: @arielma : sorry can you add backlash ``Release\\*.rdl""``

Comment: I tried it, but still gets error: `WorkflowScript: 17: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 17, column 78.
   ervices\\bin\\Release\\*.rdl""`

Comment: @arielma : Seems``\`` was missing before ``"`` as it needs to be escaped.Command is : ``bat "tar -cvzf output3.tar.gz \"C:\\Documents\\Report Services\\bin\\Release\\*.rdl\""``. This gives me results

Comment: Let's ignore the `C:\\Documents`, how the command should look now? per my understating, exactly the same as you wrote in your answer (where I got the exception): `bat "tar -cvzf output.tar.gz \"Report Services\\bin\\Release\\*.rdl\""`

Comment: @arielma in the previous comment you mentioned there was a missing ``\`` before closing``"``

Comment: You  are right :) working as expected. tnx a lot